# Default value in textbox

Tags: knockout.js

how do I want to make the textbox has default value for example '1' showing on the text box instead of empty value of the text box?

```
 <p>
   <label>Number</label><br/>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: number" />
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your observable named `number`, give it a default value.

`var number = ko.observable(1);`

Comment: thanks, it works. However, when I input another value, it can only save the default value. can u help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Here's a jsfiddle of everything working as I'd expect: http://jsfiddle.net/5msm261h/